# CakePHP SplFileInfo accessing wrong path

Tags: cakephp, caching

I moved my application form the test server to the production server, but now I'm having a problem with SplFileInfo that tries to access the path form the test server.

I tried many solutions that I found but no one worked. And I don't hav permission to change the PHP version from my server.

This erros is happening when I need to load some JS files from a Plugin called 'FileUpload'. This is printed at the top of the JS file. Can see here: http://www.mileniomoveis.com.br/file_upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js

The old (test server) path is `/storage/e/ca/fa/novomileniomoveis/public_html/...`
The new (production server) path is `/storage/5/99/da/tmpmileniomoveis/public_html/...`

Here is the error:

```
Warning: SplFileInfo::openFile(/storage/5/99/da/tmpmileniomoveis/public_html/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_cake_dev_en-us): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /storage/e/ca/fa/novomileniomoveis/public_html/Cake2.2/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 313

Warning: SplFileInfo::openFile(/storage/5/99/da/tmpmileniomoveis/public_html/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_cake_dev_en-us): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /storage/e/ca/fa/novomileniomoveis/public_html/Cake2.2/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 313

Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /storage/e/ca/fa/novomileniomoveis/public_html/Cake2.2/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 309

Warning: /storage/5/99/da/tmpmileniomoveis/public_html/tmp/cache/models/ is not writable in /storage/e/ca/fa/novomileniomoveis/public_html/Cake2.2/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 336

Warning: SplFileInfo::openFile(/storage/5/99/da/tmpmileniomoveis/public_html/tmp/cache/persistent/myapp_cake_core_file_map): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /storage/e/ca/fa/novomileniomoveis/public_html/Cake2.2/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 313
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having a problem with SplFileInfo that tries to access the path form the test server.

The path to your application files is one of the things that's cached therefore, whenever changing something fundamental in your application **delete all the tmp files** but especially the cache:

```
cd app
rm -rf tmp/cache/*/*
```

Comment: Tanks for the answer, but I already tried that many times and the error continues.

Comment: I agree, just to ensure I did that via FTP too, to see with my eyes that the cache files were deleted, and that error continues happening. I search on the web and tried many solutions, but none worked.

Comment: I tried disabling CakePHP Cache and after cleaning all cache files and still having the error. I don't explanation for this, it's freaking me out!

Comment: Yes, and I set the chmod to 777 just to ensure that it's writable and executable. I don't understand why the old path is still using. For some reason, Cake is trying to access the file engine from `/storage/e/ca/fa/novomileniomoveis/public_html/Cake2.2/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php`

Comment: Curiously this is just happing when I need to use some JS files form a Plugin.

Comment: `Can see here [link]` - there's nothing wrong there. So either you've resolved the question or you were looking at a (browser) cached version of that js file which had a stale response or some other such scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem, only browser cache. Sorry for my do doubt, but how can I rate you? Only check your answer? Because the solution wasn't that on the top of the answer. Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: Most appropriate action is to amend the question to better explain what the problem was and write your solution as an answer and accept that - there's no need to accept this answer as it wasn't the solution.